# How can I have one android app send a message to another to start it up in android O?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

Before android O, I was able to trigger the functionality of a second sister-app based on the action of a first app. I did this by sending the second app an intent that was defined as a broadcast receiver in the second app. All as well.

But apparently as of api 26, any broadcast receivers defined in the manifest that aren't particular system ones (ie, app specific ones like mine) get ignored. I get errors in the logcat to that effect, I forget the details.

The only way I can think to get this to work is to have the second app start on boot (that broadcast receiver still seems to work) and have it start a service that installs a broadcast receiver programatically, and the service keeps enough of the app alive to receive those messages.

I haven't tried that yet because that seems like overkill and very resource intensive just to receive an intent to do something.

Is there any other mechanism to make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But apparently as of api 26, any broadcast receivers defined in the manifest that aren't particular system ones (ie, app specific ones like mine) get ignored

Not true. You're misunderstanding the restriction.

As of API 26, you can no longer receive *implicit* broadcasts with a Manifest-declared receiver. However, *explicit* broadcasts are exempt.

Target the receiver explicitly in your Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my_action");
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.sister.packagename", "com.sister.packagename.Receiver");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

You'll obviously need to use your own action and the proper package/class name, but that will allow you to keep your Manifest-defined receiver.

Make sure you're checking the action in that receiver's `onReceive()` method, though. By sending an explicit broadcast, Android ignores your intent filter and sends the intent anyway.

Comment: brilliant! Yes, I did misunderstand that. Thank you.